# Difference between PECL GearmanWorker::addFunction() and GearmanWorker::register()

Tags: php, gearman

So, I'm assuming that `addFunction()` registers a "worker function name" w/ the server AND tells the worker what callable that registered name refers to.

> http://www.php.net/manual/en/gearmanworker.addfunction.php

`register()`, on the other hand, seems to ONLY register a function name w/ the job servers.

> http://www.php.net/manual/en/gearmanworker.register.php

Guess I'm not understanding the why behind ever having a worker register a function w/ the server for which it has no callable for.

Also, do I NEED to call `register()` as WELL as `addFunction()`, or is my assumption above correct that `addFunction()` will register w/ the server as well?

Comment: Your assumption is correct, taken directly from the link you supplied about the `addfunction`, *Registers a function name with the job server and specifies a callback corresponding to that function. Optionally specify extra application context data to be used when the callback is called and a timeout.*

Comment: Right.. but why in the world would you want to just register() a worker function w/o defining a call back like addFunction() does?